# Why does this Asp .net controller throw 404 "Page not found" error when deployed to cloud but work fine locally?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-service-fabric

I have a controller defined as this:

```
[Route("api/MyAPI")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet, HttpPost, Route("GetData")]
    public async Task<MyResponse> GetData()
    {
        MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
        int i = await myService.ExecuteAsync();
        response.IncomingUrl = this.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
        response.intVal = i;
        return response;
    }}
```

This throws a 404 error when deployed in service fabric cluster but works fine when deployed locally. The url I use locally is https://localhost:5400/api/MyAPI/GetData and while deployed to cloud is https://myservice.com/api/MyAPI/GetData.

When I remove the [Route("api/MyAPI")] block from on top of the class (line 1) and include it in the method as [HttpGet, HttpPost, Route("api/MyAPI/GetData")] (line 4), it works both locally and on cloud.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for RoutePrefix attribute on instead of Route for your controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/MyAPI")]
public class MyController : Controller
```

Hope this fixes the issue